# What is the meaning of 'bouts', in this phrase?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

I'm having a hard time trying to understand the word 'bouts'in the following verse of a WWE(world wrestling entertainment)theme:

(...)
Bouts so false never ever gonna lose
(...)

Also, is it working as a verb here?

Comment: Hello, Moses. Although this English is non-standard (I'd guess for say 'they put on bouts which are so false/rigged that Mammoth Muscleboy isn't ever going to lose one'), it's easy to look up 'bout' in a dictionary and find the wrestling-related definition.

Comment: ***Bout*** noun [C] (SPORT)

 
 a boxing or wrestling match:
*He's a former heavyweight champion and is expected to win the bout easily.* https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bout